MC is tested by touching an orb. Color it produces determines class/talent. It glowed white when he touched it. Meaning he has no class/talent
Probably within the last 5-10 years, English (It's also possible I am recalling a Manga series, and not a book, if it was a manga, I dont know the original language.)
MC comes of age (I don't recall the age, could have been 12, could have been 18) and along with all his age group is tested. In the testing hall before all the others of his age group and family (and teachers?) [It could have been like Hogwarts sorting hat, dividing the students into classes at their entry into school.]
Each person approaches an white orb on a stand. They touch it, and based on the color that it glows, everyone sees their talent/class. (i.e. if it glows blue they are a Water Mage, if its red they are a Fire Mage, if its green they are a Healing Mage, etc.) If I remember right there are 5-6? (maybe 8?) possible colors/talents/skills.
When they MC touches it it glows white. Meaning no talent. Everyone is shocked, the MC is then shunned, he can't get into any mage class training, and is kicked out of school, (maybe even disowned by his family?)
Now years later(?), off on his own he discovers he CAN do magic, and he can do different types, (Water, Fire, Healing, etc.)
Turns out the Orb glowed white, because when you mix all the colors of the rainbow, it produces white light. The Orb was actually saying he has all the talents/classes.
Again I am not sure if this was a book, or a manga.

Truthfully, this is a fairly common trope (testing shows no talent, but it's actually due to some sort of overflow), but the details of the colors does sound vaguely familiar.

The details of the colors was just examples, it could have been more mundane things, Red=Fighter, Green=Druid, Brown=Farmer/laborer. I.e. it could have been classes as opposed to magic categories. I just don't recall what it was, except that everyone miss-understood that White did not mean No skill, instead it meant he had All skills.

Using a variation of FuzzyBoots search terms I was able to find it. (manga magic testing turns white because all magic)
It is: "Sekai ni Hitori, Zenzokusei Mahou no Tsukaite"
(The Only Person in the World Able to Use All Magic Attributes)

My mistake was: the testing Orb turned Black, (not white) The first few pages of the first chapter, when he is born the high noble father tests him and when the orb turns black, his family thinks he is a demon baby. His parents decided to hide the birth and dispose of the baby, (they have another baby already, so he would have been the second son, and console themselves saying that one is enough) but he ended up being adopted by his uncle and aunt, who raised him.
BUT, he was one of those reincarnated from another world people, who awoke with his memories and starts studying the new world and magic. By the time he is 5, he is skilled with magic. During a family vacation in the family carriage, he rescues another carriage being attacked by many powerful monsters.
The second chapter, he explains why the Orb turned black, by poring various colored dyes into a bowl of water representing each of the colors associated with the different types of magic.
Thanks for the assistance in finding it.

Glad you found it. Of course, don't forget to accept it when you can. :)

Yep, been waiting for the timer. ;)

Might it be Ee, Nouryoku Nashi de Party Tsuihousareta Ore ga Zenzokusei Mahoutsukai?!? (no non-infringing link currently available)

Though magical abilities should awaken in anyone, Tyler, an adventurer, has yet to have awaken his own abilities awaken for some unknown reason. Because he is unable to use magic, he is left behind in the depths of a dungeon by his party leader. However, when facing against a perilous situation involving his childhood friend Ariana, who stayed behind to help him, his hidden power awakens! What he obtained was unprecedented – the ability to use all magic attributes. After safely escaping the dungeon, Tyler hears about an herb that can cure his sister’s illness, and sets a goal to challenge the super-advanced dungeon, forming a new party. A different world fantasy of running up to the strongest party with girls who believe in him starts!!

Found with a search for manga testing orb turns white because all magic

I looked at it, (found 11 chapters in English not sure if there are others not translated) And while the MC does possess all magic types, (7 total) there was NO testing scene where the orb glowed white. The MC, in a highly stressful situation, where his party (he was strategist deciding the best way to defeat monsters) abandoned him as bait to escape a very powerful monster, when his ability to use all 7 magic types suddenly emerged. In this Manga, everyone usually develops or receives their skills at about 15, and he is 17 now with no magic.
